# SQL Lag Increment By 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment

I am trying to use the LAG function to add 1 to every row, with '1' as the default value. For example;

```
SELECT 
    T.NAME,
    T.SESSION,
    LAG (CASE WHEN T.SESSION = 2023 THEN '1' END, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY T.NAME) + 1 AS 'SESSION_ORDER'
FROM 
    TABLE T 
WHERE 
    T.SESSION >= 2023
```

The query would return 4 rows, and what I'm after is to set the default value of the first row to 1 in the derived column `SESSION_ORDER`, then for the subsequent rows, increment by 1 each time so the next three rows would be;

```
2
3
4
```

The problem I'm having is that the results are as follows;

```
1
2
NULL
NULL
```

**UPDATE**: if anyone would like to run the query, or a similar one, I have used the demo select query from sqlliteonline.com;

```
SELECT 
    id, name,
    LAG (CASE WHEN name = 'CREATE' THEN 1 END, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY ID) + 1
FROM 
    demo
WHERE 
    NAME IN ('CREATE', 'SELECT', 'INSERT', 'UPDATE');
```

The output is:

```
1
2
NULL
NULL
```

Comment: We need to see the `t.Name` values to see why the `ORDER BY` doesn't seem to be applied.

Comment: set the default value to 0 : `LAG(T.SESSION,1,0)` , second parameter in LAG is the step

Comment: @eshirvana Thank you for the reply - setting the default value to 0 returns 1 for all 4 rows unfortunately...

Comment: Use `row_number` not `lag` for this. Lag won't create an incrementing sequence

Comment: also seems like you need row_number() to solve this problem , not sure why you are using LAG here , provide more detail

Comment: @Dai Thank you for the response - the T.NAME values are A23, A24, A25 and A26...

Comment: @MartinSmith Thank you for the reply, Martin - so there isn't a way of increasing using lag at all?

Comment: @GBM you are doing something wrong then or all the session id are equal to 0

Comment: @GBM Why are you seemingly fixated on using only `LAG`? Why won't you consider other approaches?

Comment: @eshirvana Hmmm I doubt it - the query is as is in the question, and as you advised I set the default value to zero. Please check out the sample query I am running on sqlliteonline.com - I have updated the question...

Comment: You can't reference the calculated lag value from a previous row inside lag so no it isn't possible to use it to recursively increase a counter by 1 in each row

Comment: @GBM in your updated query, how do you wanna add 1 to a name???!!!

Comment: @eshirvana I'm not trying to add 1 to a name, I'm trying to set 1 as the default for the first row, then increment by 1 thereafter...

Comment: Repeat: use `row_number`, not `lag`

Comment: read LAG() documentation then, you don't know what LAG actually does then

Comment: @eshirvana which is why I posted the question...to ask for assistance :)

Comment: then update your question and show your desired output, again seems like you need to use row_number() window function not LAG

Comment: @eshirvana please see revised query in question...

Comment: @GBM please provide sample data and desired output, your queries don't make sense unfortunately

Comment: and provide information about the original problem you are trying to solve : https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Or (having looked at https://sqliteonline.com/) maybe what you are attempting to do is `SELECT * , 1 + ID - FIRST_VALUE(Id) OVER (ORDER BY ID)  FROM demo WHERE NAME IN ('CREATE','SELECT','INSERT','UPDATE');` - but this is not going to be reliable in the general case

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can modify your original query using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
SELECT 
T.NAME,
T.SESSION,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.NAME) AS 'SESSION_ORDER'
FROM TABLE T 
WHERE T.SESSION >= 2023;
```

For the demo query on sqlliteonline.com:

```sql
SELECT 
id,
name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS 'SESSION_ORDER'
FROM demo
WHERE NAME IN ('CREATE','SELECT','INSERT','UPDATE');
```

This will give you a sequence starting from 1 and incrementing by 1 for each row in the result set, based on the specified `ORDER BY` clause.